# Identify the component

Tags: ac, dc, components, rectifier, homework

[image]

In the given question, I see figure 3 has a common terminal which is more likely to be a full wave rectifier and figure 4 has 4 terminals which resemble that of a bridge rectifier, am I correct in saying this, can someone identify the components.

Comment: The question needs some context. Do they relate to space shuttles or home wiring? If the latter, they are light switches.

Comment: the image is fuzzy ... they appear to be mounting bases for cabinet hinges

Answer (score 2):

They are not rectifiers. They are the back of light switches. To give you something to do for your homework you can have a go at identifying what sort of light switches they are.

Comment: Ah, so the square is a European style elecrical outlet box cover?

Comment: Different European countries have different styles of light switch cover. They could be UK switches though the holes for the retaining screws aren't shown. Irrespective of that, there is enough information written on the back of the switches for you to be able to identify which type each switch is.

Comment: Your answer will depend on where you are. The US and UK have different naming conventions for the switches in figs 3 & 4.